# Update in access with subquery

Tags: sql, ms-access

Why such query:

```
UPDATE t1 INNER JOIN (SELECT b, c FROM sometable) t2 ON t1.a=t2.b SET t1.a=t2.c
```

won't work in Access?

It's really frustrating. If I put the result of that SELECT query into a table, then the updating works. Is there any workaround?

Comment: If you say putting the results in a then using that table in the query works, is there a reason why you wouldn't use a temporary table to do just that? Select all your results from the sub query in a temp table and then join on that temp table. Or does Access not support temp tables (sorry I'm not very familiar with Access' limitations)?

Comment: it doesnt support temp tables. I would need to create "normal" table... It's a bit pain

Comment: It could still be done, but I agree it would be a pain.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert in Access, but it sounds like it doesn't support a direct join in an `UPDATE` statement.  Oracle also has this behavior, and one workaround is to use a subquery in the `SET` clause of the update:

```
UPDATE t1
SET t1.a = (SELECT c FROM sometable t2 WHERE t1.a = t2.b)
```

Comment: It does support inner join. Moreover, it is the only way to update with values from another table. The problem is with a select subquery. When I replace it with a physical table, it works.

Comment: Unfortunately,it does... Access ;/